# Command to check server port number opened or not from hp switches

Tags: switch, hp

I am facing is that to check the port number of the server is opened or not. DOnt know how to check it and also gone via various hp pdf's with no go. Like in cisco if we want to check whether the server is able to hear at some specific port then we run the command telnet ip port-number (enter). it will give us the prompt whether the window is open on that port number or not. Please respond back

Comment: The problem is that this has nothing to do with your switch. Can you telnet from your switch to a host? Sure you can, but why would you. Why wouldn't you just telnet from your workstation to the host? Why wouldn't you just run a port scan against the host or network from your workstation?

Answer (score 0):

If the service is running, and the port is opened, you will be able to telnet to the port. If the service isnt running, start it up, if you cant start it up, start something else up on that port temporarily. For example, if you are using linux, you might be able to run netcat on the port.

```
nc -l <port>
```